# How To Send Unattended Emails on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

so I have made this app in which user enters his password and login basically a locker.
I want that if the user forgets his password an email with the reset code could be sent to their email id which they entered during the first run of the app..
so far I found EmailComposeTask but it does not exactly do what I want.
is there any other way where I can send an email, or someone point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I would do this on the server that handles user request, and not on the phone itself - there are many reasons for that, starting with security infrastructure. But let's say that you still want to do it.

`EmailComposeTask` is a bad choice for your specific case, because the user is able to edit the content of the message before it is sent. Besides, if someone else, who does not carry an account on the device, but gets a hold of the device, decides to reset the password, he will be able to quickly see the outgoing reset code.

So instead, you could use a library like [LiveMailMessage](http://windowsphonegeek.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage). What this gives you is the ability to send emails in an unattended manner, like:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.Email = "test@email.id";
mailMessage.Password = "somePassword";
mailMessage.AccountType = MailMessage.accountType.MicrosoftAccount;
mailMessage.To = "destination@email.id";
mailMessage.Subject = "Reset Link";
mailMessage.Body = "Here is the reset link";
mailMessage.Send();
```

You can quickly see why this is problematic as well - you will have to secure the local password storage, since you will need to specify the credentials for the outgoing mail account.

Comment: are there any other option which are free of cost??

Comment: Implement your own mail API wrapper.